# tinymce formatting

Tags: css, tinymce

I am using the following code block to format text:

```
    'formats': {
        'format_code': {
            'block': 'pre',
            'styles': {
                'color': '#000000',
                'backgroundColor': '#f0f0f0',
                'fontFamily': 'monaco,consolas,courier new,monospace',
                'fontSize': '1.0em',
                'width': '80%',
                'minHeight': '5.0em',
                'maxHeight': '15.0em',
                'overflow': 'auto',
                'border': '1px solid #999999',
                'padding': '1.0em'
            }
        }
```

This code block was given to me. Now I would like to change it to use a CSS class.

Can anyone advise me how to do this. I am not familiar with tinyMCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS is almost identical. The [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) properties are dash seperated in CSS and the font containing a space must be quoted.

```
.myClassSelector {
    color:#000000;
    backgroundColor:#f0f0f0;
    font-family:monaco,consolas,"courier new",monospace;
    font-size:1em;
    width:80%;
    min-height:5em;
    max-height:15em;
    overflow:auto;
    border:1px solid #999999;
    padding:1em;
}
```

I assume you want to add it to the drop down *Styles* in TinyMCE. If you want to add it to the *Format* drop-down then that requires a different configuration option.

If you want a new *Style* in the drop-down then you need to put the CSS class rule above in a `.css` file and [configure TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3astyle_formats) as follows:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    theme:'advanced',
    content_css:'path/to/css/file',
    style_formats : [
        {title : 'My Style', block : 'div', classes : 'myClassSelector'}
    ]
});
```